# logstash parse json child element, format and insert into elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, logstash-configuration

I have a json file like this:

```
  "fruits": {
    "fruit": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "test",
        "tag": "fine",
        "start": "4",
        "end": "9"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "test1",
        "tag": "fine1",
        "start": "2",
        "end": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have 100s of elements inside "fruit" field. I want to:

- insert only the elements inside "fruit" field to the elasticsearch each as an individual doc. I want to use their own id as elasticsearch doc id.
- calculate numbers in between "start" and "end" fields, then add those numbers as a comma separated string to a new field inside each doc.

The docs I want to insert into elasticsearch will be as follows:

```
{
    {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
            "id" : "1",
            "label": "test",
            "tag": "fine",
            "start": "4",
            "end": "9",
            "diffs": "4,5,6,7,8,9"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
            "id" : "2",
            "label": "test1",
            "tag": "fine1",
            "start": "2",
            "end": "4",
            "diffs": "2,3,4"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with the logstash configuration file to achieve the desired output? I am using ELK version 7.x

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your current configuration of logstash file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could solve the requirement following this instruction.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-parse-json-child-element-format-and-insert-into-elasticsearch/312230/7

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.